# Remove rows based on mode

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Data:

```
 df <- data.frame("y"= c(rep(100,10), rep(103,10)), "x" = c(rep(1,8),2,2,rep(4,5),7,7, rep(4,3)) )
```

For each value of y, we expect a unique value of x. But in data, we have a couple of unwanted values. Based on mode, we can find the corresponding value of x for each value of y.

Can we identify the row numbers where there is unwanted pairing ?

Expected output:
9, 10, 16, 17

Comment: How do you know which rows are unwanted values?

Comment: please run the code . You can see x and y values. When y = 100, x is 1 (8 times) or 2( 2 times).  So right pair is (y=100, x=1) so (y=100,x =2) is unwanted and is to be removed

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ave` to group by 'y', get the logical index of elements in 'x' that are not the 'Mode', from there get the row index with `which`.

```
with(df, which(as.logical(ave(x, y, FUN= function(x) x!=Mode(x)))))
#[1]  9 10 16 17
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned in the comments, the above can be made compact

```
which(with(df, x != ave(x, y, FUN=Mode) ))
```

where `Mode` is (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode))

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
 ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Comment: You could save a bunch of comparisons and do `which(with(df, x != ave(x, y, FUN=Mode) ))`

Comment: @thelatemail That is a nice compact approach.  Thanks